# How do I change color of alert dialog of material 3 android xml

Tags: android-layout, android-alertdialog, material3

I want to change the container color of material 3 alert dialog

I tried to use things from [official documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md#theming-dialogs)
but I couldn't change the color, background color of container remains pink/purple
I am creating alert dialog like this and there are .setTheme or .setBackground methods either

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(itemView.context as AppCompatActivity)
    .setTitle("Do the thing")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to do the thing?")
    .setNeutralButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
    }
    .setPositiveButton("Do") { dialog, which ->
        doThing()
    }
    .show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom theme just for the dialog box

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/new_color</item>
</style>
```

then set it

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(itemView.context as AppCompatActivity, R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how to increase corner radius too?

Comment: when I use your method, its corner size sets to pre android 12 days how do I increase corner radius?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and retain Material 3 corner radius:

```
<style name="MaterialAlertDialogStyle" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/new_color</item>
</style>
```